# nmapで、ERROR: script execution faild (use -d to debug)と表示される

Tags: linux, network, security

kali linuxでNmapで脆弱性スキャンを行ったところ、このようなエラーが起きました。

```
|_http-stored-xss: Couldn't find any stored XSS vulnerabilities.
|_http-csrf: Couldn't find any CSRF vulnerabilities.
|_http-dombased-xss: Couldn't find any DOM based XSS.
443/tcp  open  https
|_http-csrf: Couldn't find any CSRF vulnerabilities.
|_http-dombased-xss: Couldn't find any DOM based XSS.
|_http-stored-xss: Couldn't find any stored XSS vulnerabilities.
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
|_http-aspnet-debug: ERROR: Script execution failed (use -d to debug)
|_http-vuln-cve2014-3704: ERROR: Script execution failed (use -d to debug)
8443/tcp open  https-alt
```

**まずこれをしようと思った理由が、**
metasploitでバックドアを作成する時、

```
000.00.00.0:443 - Exploit failed: EOFError EOFError
```

と出ました。

まずこれらがエラーなのか、解決策を教えてください。
初心者なので、出来るだけやさしくお願いします...

ちゃんとkali linux側のROOT権限でやってます